# How to push new item to the existing array which will have a value subtracted 10 from previous item until it will reach close to 0 or 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have one number which has a value of `[200]`.

How to push new item to the existing array which will have a value subtracted 10 from previous item until it will reach close to 0 or 0?

I was thinking about while loop but not sure.
Can anybody help to solve this please?

Comment: Please post your attempt at it

Comment: I don't know which direction to go yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A while loop will work fine:

```
const arr = [200]
while (arr[arr.length - 1] > 9) {
  arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] - 10)
}
console.log(arr)
```